# I can get all the items in a list using SPFX ... How to modify my code to just get a particular view?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have created an SPFX web part to get items from a list and it works fine.
I have one line ...

resultData = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(this.properties.listName).items.select(...colsToSelect).orderBy(localColumnToOrderBy, true).get().then((items: any) => {

which I now need to just get the items from a particular view.

Would anyone know how to modify it?

I tried ...
resultData = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(this.properties.listName).views.getByTitle("my view name")().items.select(...colsToSelect).orderBy(localColumnToOrderBy, true).get().then((items: any) => {

but it doesn't like it!

Thanks
P

Answer (score 2):

to load particular view of the list I am using renderListDataAsStream function (it has more benefits like the standard get()).

To load data:

```
if (viewId !== null) {
  const overriderenderListDataParams: any = {
    View: viewId
  };
  const renderListDataParams: any = {
    RenderOptions: 1687
  };
  rawData = await sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.ListToDisplay).renderListDataAsStream(renderListDataParams, overriderenderListDataParams);
  } else {
    const renderListDataParams: any = {
      RenderOptions: 1687
    };
    rawData = await sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.ListToDisplay).renderListDataAsStream(renderListDataParams); 
}
```

To get views for the list:

```
const viewData = await sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.ListToDisplay).views.filter('Hidden ne true').get();
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried this but it doesn't work ... const viewData = await sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.ListToDisplay).views.filter('Hidden ne true').get();

Comment: What does it return? Of course you have to change variable this.props.ListToDisplay to ID of your list.